# Can't get hello world in django

Tags: django

I tried writing the hello world program in django but i get didn't get the expected outcome. Please help- 2nd day stuck here.  My Python version 2.7. Django 1.6.2

**Directory list:**

1. mysite

   - manage.py
   - mysite

     - *init*.py
     - _init.pyc
     - settings.py
     - settings.pyc
     - urls.py
     - urls.pyc
     - wsgi.py
     - wsgi.pyc
     - views.py

**1. Code in Views file**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse(“hello world”)
```

**2. Code in urls file**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from mysite.views import hello


#from django.contrib import admin
#admin.autodiscover()

#urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    #url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.hello’, name=‘hello’)

)
```

**SyntaxError at "":**

Exception Value:
Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/********/****/djcode/mysite/mysite/urls.py on line 16, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (urls.py, line 16)
[please note: asterisk used to hide the path above]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using different characters:

`url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.hello’, name=‘hello’)`

should be:

`url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.hello', name='hello')`

so to clarify `’` should be `'` in that line of code.